# How do I convert code to a string even if the code contains all 3 types of quotes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, string, jsx

I'm trying to save code to a database and need a way to save that code without somehow erroring because they use the same quotes I wrap the code in

I've tried do this.

```
    const snippits = [
        {
            title: "random 01",
            code: String(
                <div>
                    <motion.p 
                        className='text-text bg-primary-button absolute px-4 py-2 rounded-lg shadow-lg z-10'
                        animate={{ y: [null, '0.5rem', '0rem'] }}
                        transition={{ delay: 3, times: [0, 0.2, 1] }}
                    >
                        CTRL + C
                    </motion.p>
                    <p className='text-black bg-black/50 relative px-4 py-2 rounded-lg shadow-lg top-2'>CTRL + C</p>
                </div>
            ),
            tags: ["hello", "world"],
            votes: 15,
            favorite: true
        }
    ]
```

this errors out saying that I haven't imported the framer-motion package for the "motion.p" element.  This is what is confusing though cause that portion of the code is inside the "String()" function

```
- error ReferenceError: motion is not defined
    at Home (./src/app/page.jsx:19:97)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "2300908980"
   8 |             code: String(
   9 |                 <div>
> 10 |                     <motion.p
     |                     ^
  11 |                         className='text-text bg-primary-button absolute px-4 py-2 rounded-lg shadow-lg z-10'
```

Comment: That should be erroring because it's a syntax error, since you didn't wrap the string in quotes.

Comment: What is `String(...)`? That's not standard JS.

Comment: I could wrap it in backticks but if for some reason the code contains backticks already that would cause it to error again

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: If it contains an embedded quote, you escape it.

Comment: I meant the way you have embedded HTML in the `String()` function without quoting them. It looks like a template framework.

Comment: @Barmar `String` is standard JS?

Comment: @Barmar this is JSX/React, not HTML. And it basically creates objects of the shape `{ type: "div", props: { ... }}`.

Comment: @BenjaminPhillips the Issue is `motion.p` here the `type` is a reference to a function, and that reference can not be serialized. You could replace it with a placeholder, but this means that you'd also have to do that backwards, replace the placeholder with a reference to `motion.p` then deserializing the string from the DB